# mini-Kanren, core.logic, clojure: Reasoned Scheme Exercise 60

Tags: clojure, logic, minikanren, clojure-core.logic

This is NOT homework -- the solution is already in the text. I just failed to understand the solution.

### Problem

```
(run* (q)
  (let [a (== true q)
        b (== false q)]
    b))
```

### Correct Solution

```
(false)
```

### My believed solution

```
()
```

### My Confusion

Apparently the "a (== true q)" line is NOT executed, since only b is the goal. This confuses me. My mental model so far for logic programming has been:

- consider all possible assignemnts to q
- output the ones that manages to pass through the entire program

  Thus, the "a (== true q)" forces q = true, which makes it impossible to satisfy the "b (== false q)" line.

  However, apparently only "thigns needed to compute the goal" are executed. What's going on? What's the right mental execution model for core.logic / mini-kanren?

Thanks

(BTW, I'm clearly in the wrong, since mini-karen + core.logic agre with each other -- I just want to understand what I'm doing wrong.)

Comment: When your objective is to reach the goal, it is better to leave something that isn't related to your objective to reach the goal

Comment: @Ankur: you're probably right. However, I don't understand it. Can you provide some insight on how "let" fits into the execution model of mini-kanren / core.logic? It's clearly that I do not understand what "let" means -- and it's clear that "let" means something else than in pure scheme/clojure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`==` produces a goal. But you don't pass the `a` goal to run. So run doesn't know about it. A comparable situation is this:

```
(defn call [f] (f))

(call
  (let [a #(println "a")
        b #(println "b")]
    b))
```

The `a` function is created but not passed to `call`. So it is never executed.

Comment: This makes sense now, despite fooling around with the repl, I didn't realize that == returned functions. [I thought it was just some weird type/macro trick to make core.logic work.]